# What dynamic range is needed to photograph the moon and the sun in the same frame?

Tags: visible-light, astrophotography

What dynamic range would in theory be required to photograph a total solar eclipse for real to get the effect on this commemorative stamp, with the moon illuminated by Earthshine:
[image: Total Solar Eclipse stamp]

For good measure, what dynamic range is needed to get a picture like this in a single photograph?
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about photography.

Comment: OK, JMac. Can you tell me how to move it to the photography SE please?

Comment: @Gnubie You can't, only the mods. You can ask for a reason, I personally can't find them very convincing. Only to the physics.meta and to the math SE can we move anything by community votes. You can flag it for mod intervention, sometimes they do. If they decline the flag, then delete the post and re-ask on the remote site with copy-paste.

Comment: I have voted to leave open because I think the question falls within the topics suitable for Physics SE. However, there is no attempt by the OP to answer the question himself.

Comment: In these photos the Moon is illuminated by the Sun, but the Sun is behind the Moon. The Sun cannot be in two places at once. For such a photograph the Moon would have to be illuminated by light reflected from the Earth.